# Use of undeclared type name error with a parameterized trait

Tags: rust, traits

I'm trying to implement a few operations on a parameterized type (specifically, some common "stack" operations on top of `Vec<T>`. However I'm not sure how that works (yet), so here's a stripped-down version of what I'm currently struggling with:

```
trait Stack<T> {
    fn top(&self) -> Option<T>;
}

impl Stack for Vec<T> {
    fn top<T>(&self) -> Option<T> {
        match self.len() {
            0 => None,
            n => Some(self[n-1])
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut stack: Vec<f64> = Vec::new();
    stack.push(1324.4);
    println!("{}", stack.top());
}
```

The above fails to compile (on rust nightly) with the following error:

```
test.rs:6:20: 6:21 error: use of undeclared type name `T`
test.rs:6 impl Stack for Vec<T> {
                             ^
error: aborting due to previous error
```

Comment: There's a method like .top already, called `.last()`, that you can use.

Comment: Please make sure to upvote useful answers and mark an answer as accepted if it solved your problem! If no answer is acceptable, consider leaving comments explaining why, or edit your question to phrase the problem differently.

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
impl<T> Stack<T> for Vec<T> {
    fn top(&self) -> Option<T> {
        match self.len() {
            0 => None,
            n => Some(self[n-1])
        }
    }
}
```

You need to inform the compiler about the type parameters of `Stack` relevant in the implementation.

But that's not enough: fixing this error brings up an issue with the `main` function, specifically the parameter to `println!` is of the wrong type:

```
fn main() {
    let mut stack: Vec<f64> = Vec::new();
    stack.push(42.0);
    match stack.pop() {
        None    => println!("empty stack"),
        Some(n) => println!("top: {}", n)
    };
}
```

But this fix, in turn, shows that the `top` method isn't well typed for that code. One way to fix the error:

```
trait Stack<T> {
    fn top(&self) -> Option<&T>;
}

impl<T> Stack<T> for Vec<T> {
    fn top(&self) -> Option<&T> {
        match self.len() {
            0 => None,
            n => Some(&self[n-1])
        }
    }
}
```

Edit:

- as explained by @sellibitze in the comments, the reason it doesn't work is that from the original definition of `Stack`, the compiler couldn't know that values of type `T` are copyable or at least clonable — ie. that `T` supports the [`Copy`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Copy.html) or the [`Clone`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/clone/trait.Clone.html) trait, and hence values could not be duplicated (a return by value in C++ parlance). Using a reference solves the problem as a reference to `T` is copyable
- rather than matching on the return value from `top`, I could have used the fact that `Option<T>` supports the `Show` trait when `T` implements it, which happens to be true for `f64`. This means that I could simply replace `{}` by the `{:?}` formatter in the call to the `println!` macro, and leave the rest of the original `main` function untouched.

For example:

```
fn main(){
    let mut stack: Vec<f64> = Vec::new();
    stack.push(42.0);
    println!("top: {:?}", stack.top())
}
```

Comment: Please remove `<T>` after `top`. Also, the first implementation you show should not work because it requires `T: Copy`.

Comment: @sellibitze ah yes, I did remove it in my tests, but it escaped me when I copied it back somehow, thanks! As for `Copy`, I was not sure of the reason why it did not work, but using references fixed it. I was a bit sceptical about this being optimal in the case of types like floats and ints.

Comment: "the compiler couldn't know that values of type `T` are copiable — ie. that `T` supports the `Clone` trait" - note that types that are [`Copy`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Copy.html)able are distinct from types that are [`Clone`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/clone/trait.Clone.html)able.

Comment: More correct, yes. I chimed in with an answer that shows usage of the `Copy` or `Clone` bounds, if that's what OP wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two possible implementations if you want to support returning a value, instead of a reference. Note that you **can't have both of them**. In most cases, you'll see the one with the `Clone` bound, as any type that is `Copy` should also implement `Clone`:

```
trait Stack<T> {
    fn top(&self) -> Option<T>;
}

// We have values where we duplicate by copying bits naïvely
impl<T> Stack<T> for Vec<T>
    where T: Copy
{
    fn top(&self) -> Option<T> {
        self.last().map(|v| *v)
    }
}

// We have values where we can duplicate them,
// but it might take a function call to do so
impl<T> Stack<T> for Vec<T>
    where T: Clone
{
    fn top(&self) -> Option<T> {
        self.last().map(|v| v.clone())
    }
}

fn main() {
    let stack = vec![1324.4f64];
    println!("{:?}", stack.top());
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm sure OP will appreciate your input, as I do.